# how to route with variables in wordpress url?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, slug

I have a wordpress theme template page accessible through "www.myDomain.com/documents".
The slug of the page is therefor "documents".

But i can't seem to find a way to add a ressource to the URL.
How can i add a ressource like "123" at the end and still have it go to my "documents" page?

Like so "www.myDomain.com/documents/123" with the last part being the id to get in my wordpress theme page code... right now it just ends up as a 404.

Comment: See here - https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/

Comment: Or you can see here - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26388/how-to-create-custom-url-routes

Comment: thank you so  much! the other stack overflow question was perfect! i looked all over but only found way more complicated and incomprehensible versions of it ^^'

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'documents/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=documents&documents_id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpse26388_query_vars' );
function wpse26388_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'documents_id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter('init','flushRules');
function flushRules(){ global $wp_rewrite; $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); }
```